# What is the easiest way to detect if an `\includegraphics{*.eps}` has been used in a `TeX` document?

Tags: latex, auctex

What is the easiest way to detect if one has used an `\includegraphics{*.eps}` in a tex document?

(motivation: When I have used this I would like to not use `pdflatex` and instead use the combination of `latex` and `dvipdfm` (I will take care of these).)

Answer (score 2):

I think nowadays one should drop the extension for image files completely and do only `\includegraphics{<file-name-sans-extension>}`.  The used engine will pick up the right file acc. to the extensions described in `\Gin@extensions` in `.def` files provided by [LaTeX support for color and graphics](https://github.com/latex3/graphics-def).  If you use <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> within AUCTeX, you can control the engine with [Options for TeX Processors](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Processor-Options) described in the manual.

---

A general approach to parse the argument of `\includegraphics` over possible master and child files would be to use the built-in parser in AUCTeX.  I suggest to write a style file for this purpose which can look like this:

```lisp
;;; includegraphics-parser.el --- Dummy AUCTeX style to parse argument
;;; of \includegraphics

;;; Code:

;; Needed for auto-parsing.
(require 'tex)

(TeX-auto-add-type "includegraphics-parser" "LaTeX")

(defvar LaTeX-includegraphics-parser-regexp
  '("\\\\includegraphics\\*?\\(?:\\[[^]]*\\]\\)?{\\([^}]+\\)}"
    1 LaTeX-auto-includegraphics-parser)
  "Matches the mandatory argument of \\includegraphics.")

(defun LaTeX-includegraphics-parser-auto-prepare ()
  "Clear `LaTeX-auto-includegraphics-parser' before parsing."
  (setq LaTeX-auto-includegraphics-parser nil))

(defun LaTeX-includegraphics-parser-auto-cleanup ()
  "Search for \"eps\" in parsed arguments of \\includegraphics."
  (when (string-match "\\.eps"
              (mapconcat #'car (LaTeX-includegraphics-parser-list) "|"))
    (message "Found eps file extension")
    (sit-for 2)))

(add-hook 'TeX-auto-prepare-hook #'LaTeX-includegraphics-parser-auto-prepare t)
(add-hook 'TeX-auto-cleanup-hook #'LaTeX-includegraphics-parser-auto-cleanup t)
(add-hook 'TeX-update-style-hook #'TeX-auto-parse t)

(TeX-add-style-hook
 "includegraphics-parser"
 (lambda ()
   ;; Make sure graphicx.el is loaded
   (TeX-run-style-hooks "graphicx")

   ;; Hook into AUCTeX parser
   (TeX-auto-add-regexp LaTeX-includegraphics-parser-regexp))
 LaTeX-dialect)

;;; includegraphics-parser.el ends here
```

Set the variable `TeX-style-private` to a directory of your choice, e.g.:

```lisp
(setq TeX-style-private "~/.emacs.d/mystyles")
```

and save `includegraphics-parser.el` there.

Customize `TeX-parse-self` to `t` and restart Emacs.

Put something like this in your .tex file

```latex
\iffalse
\usepackage{includegraphics-parser}
\fi
```

and hit <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd> to reparse your file.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer the original question. A solution could be a regexp searching `\\includegraphics{[^}]*\.eps`. I asked my question to know if there is a better solution.

Comment: @Name - Your question was "what is the **easiest** way".  Using a regexp doesn't fit the bill `;-)` See my updated answer.